# Which Azure App Service should I pick for a ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When setting up an App Service I can chose between App Service and App Service Linux.

The difference is that App Service runs on Windows Server and App Service Linux runs on Linux, but is there any practical difference?

Does it matter which one I pick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some limitations for [App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#limitations). If you just want to have a web app service used only for development and testing purposes, you can select the free or shared tier of App Service on windows for a few cost. Or select the proper tier for your web app service depending on these features do you want.

> Some features, such as virtual network integration, Azure Active
>   Directory/third-party authentication, or Kudu site extensions, are not
>   available yet. Once these features are available, we will update our
>   documentation and blog about the changes.
>
> App Service on Linux is only supported with Basic, Standard, and
>   Premium app service plans and does not have a Free or Shared tier. You
>   cannot create Web App for Containers in an App Service plan already
>   hosting non-Linux Web Apps. There is a current limitation in regards
>   to not mixing Windows and Linux apps in the same resource group as
>   well.

Comment: If a developer have a cross-platform ASP.NET Core app, have no interested in virtual network integration, Azure Active Directory, Kudu site extensions, etc and aims to use the Basic, Standard or Premium app service plan, is there any reason to chose any App Service or App Service Linux over the other?

Comment: If so, I think the key difference is the OS difference hosting your app. There is no real impaction on your current app.